# Number translation with 118n module

Tags: drupal-7, translation, multilingual

I have developed a multi-lingual site with i18n module (7.x-1.13) and everything works as expected.My Drupal version is 7.34.

Recently, my client have asked not to translate the number. The website works in English and Arabic.

To be more specific, when Arabic is chosen, we do not want the numbers to be displayed in Arabic, instead we need to display the same in English. Now, each numbers are translated to Arabic when the language is chosen as Arabic, even the user input.

The default language is Arabic and I haven't installed any modules for translation of numbers.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was with the font that I was using when Arabic is loaded. This made the English numeric digits to convert to Arabic automatically. I have now made the same font to be loaded in both the languages. This solved my problem.